# Committing deployment failed when publishing dynamic components

Tags: 2011-sp1, deployer, dynamic-publishing

We are not able to publish dynamic components. We are getting the following error in Committing Deployment phase. The same component can be published successfully in other targets.

We are using SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1. The dynamic components are stored in database.

```
com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager - Final attempt failed for transaction: tcm:0-1268498-66560
com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-1268498-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to commit transactions, There was no longer an active transaction for: tcm:0-1268498-66560, There was no longer an active transaction for: tcm:0-1268498-66560
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.commitTransaction(TransactionManager.java:495)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.doCommit(TransactionManager.java:416)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.doTransactionControl(TransactionManager.java:304)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:131)
        at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:174)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Embedded exception:
com.tridion.broker.StorageException: There was no longer an active transaction for: tcm:0-1268498-66560
        at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:367)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.commitTransaction(TransactionManager.java:493)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.doCommit(TransactionManager.java:416)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.doTransactionControl(TransactionManager.java:304)
        at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:131)
        at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:174)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
:
```

can some one let me knwo what has gone wrong.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Deployer?

Comment: Are there any other references in the logs to the transaction: 0-1268498-66560 ?

You can also set so that the transaction files aren't removed in order confirm they are landing correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solved this by dropping down the number of workers for the Deployer to three:

```
<Location Path=".../work" WindowSize="20" Workers="3" Cleanup="true" Interval="15s"/>
```

We think the server threads were being over worked according to the logs:

> StorageManagerTransactionMonitor - Rolling back a stale transaction:
>   tcm:0-9818926-66560, transaction was waiting for: 124720 ms.

This transaction was waiting for over 124 seconds to read the data directory.

Their might be a deeper issue, but for now, we are able to successfully publish.

Hope that helps!